# Js animation to simulate encryption decryption

Tags: javascript, animation, text, simulation

I want running or shuffling text pretending the encryption decryption algorithm in action.

This code is working for numbers but I want this for a string.

```
<p class="count">0000000001</p>

<script>   
$('.count').each(function () {
                $(this).prop('Counter',100000000000000000).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 10000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic approach, I would use `String.fromCharCode()` to randomly return a letter (Ascii code between 97 and 122) and a loop to produce the definitive chain:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {  // stackoverflow.com/a/24152886/5156280
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function returnLetter() {
  return String.fromCharCode(getRandomInt(97, 122))
}

function returnRandomString() {
  var str = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    str += returnLetter()
  }
  return str
}

$('.count').each(function() {
  $(this).prop('Counter', 100000000000000000).animate({
    Counter: $(this).text()
  }, {
    duration: 10000,
    easing: 'swing',
    step: function (now) {                 
      $(this).text(returnRandomString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="count">0000000001</p>
```